# Hi, is there a way to make the date autocomplete in a Date Input box by pressing the tab button in angular?

Tags: angular, primeng

Hi i am trying to achieve something: Once User gives date in Date Input box then current month and year should be automatically add. It should accept comma seprataor values and should be format. Any idea how to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ngx-datepicker

[ngx-datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker)

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Datepicker"
        bsDatepicker
        [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-red' }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Its simple as above.kindly check the documentation for better picture!